# sklearn: Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

Hey there I'm using `Label Encoder` and `Onehotencoder` in my machine learning project sample but an error appeared while executing the code at the part where `Onehotencoder` executed and the error was `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.` and my feature column has only two attributes `Negative` or `Positive`.

What does this error message mean and how do I fix it

```py
#read data set from excel 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('diab.csv')
feature=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
lablel=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values

#convert string data to binary 
#transform sting data in lablel column to decimal/binary 0 /1
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

lab=LabelEncoder()
lablel=lab.fit_transform(lablel)
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder()
lablel=onehotencoder.fit_transform(lablel).toarray()



#create trainning model and test it 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(feature,lablel,test_size=0.30)



#fitting SVM to trainnong set 
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier=SVC(kernel='linear',random_state=0)
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred=classifier.predict(x_test)


#making the confusion matrix 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm=confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

my_classifier=KNeighborsClassifier()

my_classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
prediction=my_classifier.predict(x_test)

print(prediction)


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print (accuracy_score(y_test,prediction))

plot=plt.plot((prediction), 'b', label='GreenDots')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide the error message as you got it, with line numbers and stack trace.

Comment: "onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder()

lablel=onehotencoder.fit_transform(lablel).toarray()
"
at these lines of code

Comment: Could you print the shape of `label` before you pass it to OneHotEncoder?

Comment: the shape was one d array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you have 2 possible labels and are treating them as separate values.  The output of an SVM is usually a single value, so your labels need to be a single value for each sample.  Instead of mapping the labels to one hot vectors, instead just use a single value of `1` when the label is positive and a value of `0` when the label is negative.